# Can someone explain this prime list generator for me?

Tags: python, list

This is apparently a very fast prime list generator (
[Fastest way to list all primes below N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python/3035188#3035188)), but I can't understand some parts of it, mostly because of the syntax.

```
def rwh_primes1(n): 
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    sieve = [True] * (n/2)
    for i in xrange(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i/2]:
            sieve[i*i/2::i] = [False] * ((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)
    return [2] + [2*i+1 for i in xrange(1,n/2) if sieve[i]]
```

Why `sieve` is defined as `[True]` (a boolean) multiplied by an integer?

What means `if sieve[i/2]`?

What means `sieve[i*i/2::i]`, especially the `::i` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like it's just array notation you're looking for.

`[a] * 5` just becomes `[a,a,a,a,a]`

`if sieve[i/2]` is checking if the value of `sieve` at `i/2` is `True` or `False`

and the `::` defines the stride.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509377/432913) answer.